# windows batch file doesn't work

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I have a batch file and it doesn't work. The funny thing is all the commands work while running inside of the cmd window.

The NON-WORKING - FAULTY line from batch file:

```
    for /F %%i in ('dir /B C:\Users\Jacek2\Desktop\USB\test\1\depesza*') do (
move /Y C:\Users\Jacek2\Desktop\USB\test\1\"%%i" C:\Users\Jacek2\Desktop\USB\test\1\depesza.cvs && start /wait E:\EasyPHP-12.0\mysql\bin\mysqlimport.exe --columns=typ_raportu,kod_stacji --user=root --password= --host=127.0.0.1 --fields-enclosed-by="\"" --fields-terminated-by="," --fields-escaped-by="" test C:\Users\Jacek2\Desktop\USB\test\1\depesza.csv)
```

From CMD window:

```
    c:\>for /F %i in ('dir /B C:\Users\Jacek2\Desktop\USB\test\1\depesza*') do move
/Y C:\Users\Jacek2\Desktop\USB\test\1\"%i" C:\Users\Jacek2\Desktop\USB\test\1\de
pesza.cvs && start /wait E:\EasyPHP-12.0\mysql\bin\mysqlimport.exe --columns=typ
_raportu,kod_stacji --user=root --password= --host=127.0.0.1 --fields-enclosed-b
y="\"" --fields-terminated-by="," --fields-escaped-by="" test C:\Users\Jacek2\De
sktop\USB\test\1\depesza.cvs
```

The batch file works when I remove the code below from my batch file.

```
&& start /wait E:\EasyPHP-12.0\mysql\bin\mysqlimport.exe --columns=typ_raportu,kod_stacji --user=root --password= --host=127.0.0.1 --fields-enclosed-by="\"" --fields-terminated-by="," --fields-escaped-by="" test C:\Users\Jacek2\Desktop\USB\test\1\depesza.csv)
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: the lines in your batch file and what your writing directly in cmd are not similar. check it and rerun

Comment: What happens? Unexpected result? Error message? Explain!

Comment: the command line 'for' is not executing properly, not even moving the  txt files as cvs files, 
I don't know if there are any errors as I cannot stop the batch script (tried pause at the end of batch file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  If it's not a cmd length issue then the double quotes further along are being taken as a window title.  The leading "" stop that issue.

```
start "" and the rest of your command
```

Comment: I just tried 
&& copy C:\Users\Jacek2\Desktop\USB\test\1\depesza.cvs C:\Users\Jacek2\Desktop\USB\test\1\depesza1.cvs
So I can say the issue is with the start command

Ok so I have done as you said start and the rest command in ""

there is a progress one file was moved as cvs then I got error message windows cannot find '--fields-terminated-by=,'. Make sure you typed the name correctly and try again.
Now it has something to do with "

Comment: Just checked it again and can say that the second part && start.... is still not executing due to the error message but the moving works

The strange thing is why I can run this command in cmd window but cannot run it in .bat file?
The only thing I have changed is %i (running in window cmd) to %%i (running as a .bat file) as sugested on the Microsoft website.

Comment: Did you put your command INSIDE the `""` ?  It's meant to be after the `""`

Comment: This is how I put the command and there is an error like I said above.

&& start /wait "E:\EasyPHP-12.0\mysql\bin\mysqlimport.exe --columns=typ_raportu,kod_stacji --user=root --password= --host=127.0.0.1 --fields-enclosed-by="\"" --fields-terminated-by="," --fields-escaped-by="" test C:\Users\Jacek2\Desktop\USB\test\1\depesza.csv"

Comment: Just read fox's answers 20 times 
and changed the code to:
&& start /wait "" E:\EasyPHP-12.0\mysql\bin\mysqlimport.exe --columns=typ_raportu,kod_stacji --user=root --password= --host=127.0.0.1 --fields-enclosed-by="\"" --fields-terminated-by="," --fields-escaped-by="" test C:\Users\Jacek2\Desktop\USB\test\1\depesza.csv

The command works now.

Any idea why do I have to put "" after start in a batch file but not when I am running the same command in the cmd window mode?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest escaping each of the `&` with `^`

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?
Do you want me to write &^&^?

Comment: I have tried:

....depesza.cvs ^&^& start /wait E:\EasyPHP-12.0\.....
Now both commands are not working "move" and "start"

Comment: I'm not familiar with `mysqlimport.exe` - perhaps the `\"` to escape the `enclosed-by` `"` itself needs to be escaped. There is a similar problem with `findstr`. Maybe an extra pair of `\` would cure the batch problem. It may also explain the `windows cannot find '--fields-terminated-by=,'.` error. The parser really wasn't designed to cope with complex expressions. The changes made over the past fifteen years or so really weren't particularly well thought through and the entire mechanism had to be maintained with one eye on existing procedures. It's a wonder that it works at all...

Comment: The issue was with 

Command START Parameter

"title" : Specifies the title to display in Command Prompt window title bar. 

That is something new to me. I though the window title is optional.

I would have no problems to do the same code in php or python but I have decided to do it as batch file and take full advantage of the tools the system provides you. 

Moreover I was puzzled why the code above executes with no problems from cli but the batch file (the same code) is not.

BTW I like and fully agree with your "about me".